# What kind of material is used to ground the inside of the laptop?

Tags: headphones, ground

When I cleaned my laptop there was some "dust" at the area as specified at the image below. I removed it thinking that it was dust. Later on I bought a new headset and the microphone is buzzing whenever the laptop or when the monitor is plugged in. I think this issue is caused from the "wool" I removed. What kind of material is that?

[image: The stuff I removed image]

Comment: Whatever you remove most definitely was not the source of a grounding, that requires, an actual connection to ground. Material randomly located within the enclosure of a laptop provides no source to ground, it would be a floating ground, which is more dangerous than no grounding

Comment: If the microphone is buzzing then there is a signal going *to* it, which indicates that the headset is wired incorrectly or the connector pinout is not compatible with the laptop's audio connector. Which make and model of laptop is it? Does the headset have one connector or two?

Comment: Laptops receive ground via the battery and power supply, not from the casing. Casings that are metal/metal or carbon composite will get grounded from the motherboard's screws, as all screw holes are grounding points _(this prevents a difference of potential and ground loops)_, but that's not how the motherboard itself is grounded.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's an asus rog gl552vw and the headset has two connectors, one for microphone and one for sound.

Comment: @DrilonAliu I may have taken the question too literally: is the microphone itself making a sound, as if it was a speaker?

Comment: @AndrewMorton When I play audio, the music is fine. I record a video with microphone, and then it makes a bzzz sound(when the laptop is plugged in). The microphone grabs other sounds but it just adds the bzzz in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can pull it apart with a light touch then it was just dust, likely due to fans pulling in air from unexpected places or pushing it into crevasses.

"Wool" materials would be a risk as small conductive fibres could break away and short sensitive components.

Actual shielding would be done using proper metal pieces and shielding meshes. They are unlikely to be loosely shoved into gaps. The softest material for emi shielding would be a conductive foam or a conductive mesh wrapped around a foam. The foam would absolutely be expected to be solid and not prone to breaking apart as that would be a risk to other components.

An example EMI mesh around a foam core:

[image]